# how to display a notification as like as reminder?

Tags: android, notifications, reminders

i have implemented sample application to get the notification.i would like to display a notification when user entered a time and system time are equal then the notification should appear and also appear in on pause like reminder.Here i have used digital clock,i can able to see digital clock time it is running.when the user time and system time are equal that notification is not displaying.

i have written code as follows

```
             //This is for get the system time
             DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
         systime = df.format(new Date());// system time formate is :HH:MM:SS

              //thi is for user entered data

               usertime="HH:MM:SS";

               if(systime.equals(usertime))
                {
                  notify();   //calling notify method to get the notification
                 }
```

it is not displaying any notification when usertime and systime are equals like reminder.

how can i display notification still the systime and usertime are equal like reminder notification?

please any body help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Wrote a tutorial. Notification Reminders: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use AlarmManager to schedule notification.

Comment: can u give sample app on using AlarmManager?

Comment: i can accepted but could please give small sample code on it?